# Calling top.document

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

```
function RemoveOZELMESAJ(){
$('#OZELMESAJ').remove();
}
```

this using in iframe i want this work in top
how i can work like this usage in jquery is it possible?

```
$(".loading",top.document)
RemoveOZELMESAJ() > working parente top ?
```

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.loading', window.parent.document)
```